# Why do we have an infinite number of possible quantum gates?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

This question came to me during an online lecture by Prof. Nike Dattani, he mentioned that we have "an unlimited number of quantum gates". Simply my question is: why do we have an unlimited number of quantum gates?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5549/55

Comment: Welcome to this community! I hope this community serves you well and that you have an enjoyable time here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quantum gates transform valid qubits (or sets of qubits) into valid qubits (or sets of qubits). There's an infinite number of valid qubits, for example we can choose any value of $\theta$ in the following equation that parameterizes a single qubit:

$$
\sin \theta | 0\rangle + \cos\theta |1\rangle\tag{1}.
$$

If we start with a qubit such as $|0\rangle$, a quantum gate can transform it into any of the qubits that are possible in Eq. 1. We can have as many quantum gates as we can have values of $\theta$, and the number of possible values of $\theta$ is uncountably infinite.

In conclusion, since the number of possible valid qubits is uncountably infinite, the number of possible quantum gates is also uncountably infinite. In classical computing we only have two possible states for a bit: 0 and 1. Therefore the number of possible 1-bit gates is limited to the NOT gate and the IDENTITY gate.

Comment: Why, then, is $\theta$ continuous?

Comment: @MarkSpinelli That seems like a good question for a post of its own, rather than being piggybacked onto the answer to this one!